# FeynArts field insertion problem

Tags: packages, physics, feyncalc

I'm trying insert this scattering into FeynArts as kaon decay (Up quark and anti strange quark to anti muon and neutrino ):

[image]

but can't figure out why no field enter into 2->2 topologies

```
InsertFields[topo, {F[3, {1}], -F[4, {2}]} ->
{-F[2, {2}], F[1, {2}]},InsertionLevel -> {Classes}
, Model -> "SM"]
```

any idea how to fix this?

is there any other way to simulate kaon decay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable CKM mixing first. E.g.

```
<< FeynArts`

$FAVerbose = 0;
$CKM = True;

tops = CreateTopologies[0, 2 -> 2];
diags = InsertFields[
   tops, {F[3, {1}], -F[4, {2}]} -> {-F[2, {2}], F[1, {2}]}, 
   InsertionLevel -> {Classes}];
Paint[diags, ColumnsXRows -> {2, 1}, SheetHeader -> None,  
  Numbering -> None, ImageSize -> {512, 256}];
```

[image]